# Redirect if specific URL is given with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

I have a very straightforward url friendly htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

So `domain.com/something` is mapped to `domain.com/index.php?id=something`.

Every URL can have an additional parameter, so for example `domain.com/something` can be in the form of `domain.com/something?custom_value`

Now I need to address this particular situation: If a particular ID is matched, then a custom value must be forced. So, if I go to `domain.com/somethingelse` I want to be redirected to `domain.com/somethingelse?custom_value`

I've tried different rules with no luck. This was my last attempt but I get a message that the server is making a rediretion that will never be completed.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(somethingelse)/?$ /somethingelse?custom_value
```

Another attempt was this, resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(somethingelse)/?$ somethingelse?custom_value
```

complete htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(somethingelse)/?$ somethingelse?custom_value
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
```

**EDIT 1:**

Well, apparently this rule works (not always) on local machine, but no online server

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^somethingelse$ somethingelse?custom_value
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've also tried (also works on local machine, but no online server)

```
RewriteRule ^/somethingelse$ /somethingelse?test [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT 3**
These are my virtualhosts:

local virtual host

```
<VirtualHost vhostname>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/project
    <Directory /var/www/path/to/project>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

server virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/project
    <Directory /var/www/path/to/project
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What us the URL that you want to show to your clients or browsers?

Comment: You’re getting an endless redirect here, because only the path component of the URL is matched against your pattern - so `/somethingelse?custom_value` still matches `^/(somethingelse)/?$` the next time. Try a combination of RewriteCond and -Rule instead, something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^custom_value$` `RewriteRule ^somethingelse/?$ /somethingelse?custom_value [R=301,L]`

Comment: @anubhava if a client type `domain.com/anything` or `domain.com/anything?custom_value` then I'll leave it as it is. but if the client type `domain.com/specificmatch` then it must be redirected to `domain.com/specificmatch?custom_value`

Comment: @misorude I'll try that later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^somethingelse/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?custom_value [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser or test it after completely clearing your browser cache.